# How to resolve ClassCastException while trying to read values from cache (Ehcache)

Tags: java, classloader, ehcache

> Error while running com.processors.d task. Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException com.person.PersonAction cannot be cast to   com.person.PersonAction

When a reload happens, the PersonAction class is loaded again but the cache element value (PersonAction) in the cache remains the same resulting in the exception.

Comment: There could be a problem of different versions of the class `PersonAction`, did you change the code recently and are you using any persistence?

Comment: No. I can clearly see that the class loader of PersonAction class after the reload is different from the one stored in cache.

Comment: Please add information about the environment in which the application runs. App server? OSGi? other? Also add the Ehcache version and configuration.

Comment: It runs in a OSGi environment.. Ehcache version: 2.10.1.0_78 cache is eternal.

Comment: What do you mean by reload? You mean the module containing the PersonAction was reloaded?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577936/spring-boot-devtools-causing-classcastexception-while-getting-from-cache