# Spring Boot App. running with Intellij leads to ClassCastException on the same classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, intellij-idea, classloader

I have a Spring Boot Application which uses Jetty as Web Server, I also use gradle to build the application into executable .jar.

When I run my application with IntelliJ run or debug option, I suddenly get a class cast exception inside one of my controllers:

```
ClassCastException: com.test.matan.GenericParameter can not be cast into com.test.matan.GenericParameter
```

Its the same class as you can see. This class is a part of a dependency module of my Application, which I developed.

When I run my application with the executable jar: "java -jar my-app.jar" the **same** process works just fine, no exceptions and casting works fine as expected.

I came to a conclusion that IntelliJ is in charge of this strange "bug", but I don't understand how can I fix it. Running the application directly from the IDE is much more convenient and easier.

Any ideas? appreciated!

Edit: I use IntelliJ 2017 and can not update for now due to work's network limitations.

Comment: As a temporary solution, I added "JAR Application" in IntelliJ configurations, and I run my application through the .jar file.

Comment: Maybe this one contains a more insightful solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577936/spring-boot-devtools-causing-classcastexception-while-getting-from-cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because `spring-boot-devtools` has a class loader, but IntelliJ has it's own class loader. Removing `spring-boot-devtools` from pom.xml solved this for me.
Also you can just remove it from the libraries list in your project:

```
Project Settings -> Libraries -> find spring-boot-devtools -> delete
```

Comment: Why not simply flag this a duplicate question as the symptoms seem to be same. OP has not mentioned anything about using devtools.

Comment: When I read the other answer originally, it did not make sense because it has to do with something other than IntelliJ. I don't think the question is a duplicate.

Comment: OK, this makes sense! Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Why not disabling IntelliJ class loader instead? In my case the same project - on Eclipse - works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [clearing Intellij cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Cleaning_System_Cache.html#c2cf5b3e), that often helps with strange bugs like these.

If the problem persists, please check your run configuration and make sure that it's doing the same as `java -jar my-app.jar` command.